# Codeception/Doctrine2: Calling 'grabEntityFromRepository' before 'canSeeInRepository' causes the latter to break

Tags: doctrine-orm, codeception, symfony4

An odd one. I'm testing a REST API using Codeception and Symfony4/Doctrine2.

If a test has a single call to `$I->canSeeInRepository(...);`, it works fine.

However, if I make a call to `$I->grabEntityFromRepository(...);` (which works fine) before making this call, the `$I->canSeeInRepository(...);` call fails.

It seems like some kind of Doctrine issue.

Can anybody shed some light? Many thanks.

```
/**
 * @param ApiTester $I
 */
public function testConvertOfferToTemplate(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    /** @var \App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\Offer $offer */
    $offer = $I->grabEntityFromRepository(\App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\Offer::class, [
        'notes' => 'SOME NOTES - Custom Offer final draft',
        'dateArchived' => null,
    ]);

    $I->sendPOST('/offer-templates', json_encode([
        'name' => 'Codeception Created Template From Offer',
        'offer_id' => $offer->getId(),
    ]));

    $json = array(
        'offer_template' =>
            array(
                'name' => 'Codeception Created Template From Offer',
                'charge_period' => $offer->getChargePeriod(),
                'charge_amount' => $offer->getChargeAmount(),
                'charge_currency' => $offer->getChargeCurrency(),
                'terms' => $offer->getTerms(),
                '_embedded' =>
                    array(),
            ),
    );

    $I->seeResponseContainsJson($json);

    $I->canSeeInRepository(\App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\OfferTemplate::class, [
        'name' => 'Codeception Created Template From Offer', // FAILS
    ]);

}

/**
 * @param ApiTester $I
 */
public function testOfferCreatedFromTemplate(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->canSeeInRepository(\App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\OfferTemplate::class, [
        'name' => 'Codeception Created Template From Offer', // PASSES
    ]);
}
```

Comment: how does it fail?

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me. Basically, if I call 'canSeeInRepository' in the same test after calling 'grabEntityFromRepository', it returns false. If I call it in a separate test immediately afterwards (exact same code) then it returns true.

Comment: I've added the code I'm using above - notice the line marked 'FAILS' and 'PASSES' (identical code)